# Can i input two layers in data driven pages

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data, data-driven-pages

I have created data driven pages with one shapefile, but now i want to input another shapefile.
Is it possible with data driven pages or another way?

Edit:

I want to intersect with DDP, like this in this pic:
[image]

Comment: Please can you provide more information or a screenshot of what you want to achieve as it is currently unclear. Are you wanting to create a new set of DDP or add a second shapefile to your existing DDP?

Comment: yes i want to add a second shapefile at existing DDP,

Comment: I'm still not clear. Are you simply wanting to add another layer like this: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000000v000000 or does it need to interact with the DDP and if so how?

Comment: I post an answer!

Comment: OK, I think you need to take a look at either of these pages: http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s900000005000000 or http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s50000002z000000 to display the black polygon for all the red polygons that sit within it.

Comment: No, there cannot be more than one DPP index layer at a time. I'm still unclear on what you are trying to do, but I suspect @MAJ742 is on the right track with extent indicators.

Comment: This appears doable using ArcPy, and can possibly use less code by incorporating DDP.  However, I think you need to edit your question to explain how you choose which black polygon in the overview corresponds to the current (red) polygon in the index layer.  Is the black polygon ID recorded in the attribute table of the index layer, or is the black polygon chosen by its overlap, or ...?  Is ArcPy in-scope as an answer?  Can you include the names of your two layers so that any answers can reference them?